# What in Heavens is this error complaining about?

Tags: errors

Okay, I am quite frustrated with LateX to the point I had to curse at my computer which, obviously, has no ears no intelligence to understand where my frustration comes from.

Anyway, it is now giving me this extremely bizarre error which is essentially telling me nothing but the fact that it's unhappy like a new born child crying like crazy when it has its diaper changed and fed properly and had a good long nap in a well air-conditioned and quiet room with its baby bottle and full of toys to play with. What is the problem??

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jsarticle}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{jarticle}
%\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{color}

\usepackage{lab}

\title{Dude}
\author{seriously,}
\headding{please stop crying and tell me what your problem is, Latex}
\date{07/07/2015}

\oddsidemargin=-0.5cm %-1.3cm
\textheight=25 cm
\textwidth=17cm

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\newpage

A true expert in causing extreme stress

\end{document}
```

It has been working fine until some point(I did not alter any commands, I was peacefully writing the report). the error it keeps spitting out is,

```
line11
!Undefined control sequence.
```

In which, the "line 11" amounts to the \author{} bit. So I tried deleting that line then the \headdings{} command comes to line 11 but huzzah, it still complains that line11 is "undefined."

I can keep making new lines instead so that there is NOTHING written in line11. No commands, no texts, nothing. But it STILL tells me line11 has an undefined control sequence lol. Is...an empty line a control sequence? Do I need to define it?lol

I mean, why is it disliking line 11 so much? It almost made me laugh really, I can keep killing commands that comes to line11 but it keeps saying there is a problem is line11. I have given up, what in heavens does LateX have against line11?? What am I supposed to do???

I am all ears for any useful help. LateX may be too logical ending up t be practically illogical here, no idea in any way imaginable what the issue is. I see no issue at all!

Comment: Are you saving the file before compiling it again?

Comment: How is `\headding` defined?

Comment: I agree with @Mico and want to extend on his question: If you remove the line with the `headding` stuff, the document compiles. (Although I did not have package `lab.sty`, so maybe it is defined in `lab.sty`?)

Comment: The warning means that the command `\headding` has not been defined, either in the LaTeX format, or in the `jsarticle.cls` class file, or in the packages you load. It would be useful to state above that `jsarticle` requires the `platex` format.

Comment: Try adding this line after `\usepackage{lab}`: `\newcommand{\headding}[1]{\relax}` This defines the command `\headding` to do nothing. It should compile then.

Comment: I would assume that `\headding` is mis-spelled. What happens if you write `\heading` instead? The macro `\heading` may be defined in the document class you employ.

Comment: The undefined control sequence error in the log is a multi-line error message that tells you exactly which command is undefined.

Comment: Would it be possible to rephrase the question to not sound like a little boy who is angry about his broken toy?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, well 1. \headdings{} gives this header on the top right hand side. And no, apparently it's not a typo as it has been there like so before the error and I just tried spelling it as \heading{} just in case but no, still an error. And the lab.sty is a file already defined, which, I can paste it right here if necessary, but it is very long. And I did not see it as an issue since, well it's been 2 weeks since I started working with this latex report and lab.sty, \headdings{} have all been there, and not altered ever since, causing no issue/error.

Comment: I'm still fiddling around to try to make it work, but any other suggestions...?  I've tried to make the issue clear so if it isn't, please point out specifically where so I can add some details... And Johannes_B well, while I anticipated someone trying to bite back at my temper with LaTeX(there's always at least one person), I hoped it'd come along with some helpful suggestion, but thanks anyway.

Comment: `\headding` or `\headdings`? And is the command from `lab.sty` or what? `jsarticle` seems to suggest (p. 30) that you load the option `empty`, `plain`, `headings`, or `myheadings` somewhere/somehow, but I can't read the documentation. Do you have to pick the pagestyle via `\pagestyle{headings}`..?

Comment: Thanks for answering jon. Bizarrely, I got it fixed....and I don't know why. I copied the entire text/commands between \begin{document} and \end{document}, cut it out, compiled it and got an error-free blank pdf. Then, I pasted the stuff I just cut out back into it, compiled it (which theoretically should give me the same error, since, well, it's back to the original state) and worked without error. I really have no idea. the comman in question is \headding{} by the way...looking at lab.sty, yes it seems like the command is defined there.

Comment: Well, that's something. I guess the question can stay closed then.

Answer (score 12):

The error message you get from `platex` is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \headding
              {please stop crying and tell me what your problem is, Latex}
?
```

and it's pretty much clear: the control sequence `\headding` is not defined.

It's probably a typo and you should type `\heading` (one “d”), but it also seems to be a thing in `lab.sty`, so it's difficult to say more, unless you give a pointer to the file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice.I've commented above but, so, I did try re-spelling it as \heading{} which still gives me the error. And, I even deleted that command but then, the error complains about \date{} which I deleted so line 11 is completely blank and empty. Still, it complains. And lab.sty is defined in the same file the latex file is and well, for the past 2 weeks since I have stated working with this report, it worked and saved just fine....should I post what lab.sty is here? It's quite long(got it as a template), so how can I, if I should?

Comment: @Melba1993 If neither the class nor the packages you load define `\heading` or `\headding`, then how can TeX know about it?

Comment: Hi, egreg, taking a look at lab.sty, it does define \headding{} so I guess that isn't a problem. Especially because I have no memory of editing it....But, I commented above, how this question got solved...very strangely. Anway, thanks for the suggestion, I appreciated your time for this problem!

Comment: @Melba1993 I'm curious: is this `lab.sty` publicly available? Other question: so it is *always* line 11 that throws the error? Open the `log` file and look at the error message: what's written after `l.11` (in the same line) there?

Comment: Hey clemens, lab.sty was available on cloud latex(something like overleaf but is enable both in english and japanese) as a template but it has been removed recently(no idea why). I'll try tying them out here, if that gives you an idea(I'm obviously no expert in this)    \typeout{Document Style Option 'Weekly Meeting Memo' Ver.3, (93.May) by K.Hosoda}

Comment: \def\headding#1{\gdef\@headding{#1}}

\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 \begin{flushright} {\@date \par} {\@headding} \end{flushright}
 \vskip 2em \begin{center}
 {\LARGE \@title \par} \vskip 1.5em {\large \lineskip .5em
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author 
 \end{tabular}\par} 
            \end{center}
 \par
 \vskip 1.5em} 
\headding{Asada Lab. Weekly Meeting Memo\\���c�������������}

\def\abstract{\if@twocolumn
\section*{�E�v}
\else \small 
\begin{center}
{\bf �E�v\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}} 
\end{center}
\quotation 
\fi}

Comment: ....and it goes on. and yes, the line was always 11. Always. I've edited the text quite a lot now, the log doesn't seem to be left for the error now. But as posted above, the error definitely told me "! undefined control sequence" "emergency stop." I am assuming that would have been the error shown in the log anyway? Or is there a possibility it is different...

Comment: @Melba1993 Is it possible to give a pointer to `lab.sty`? It seems to be the heart of the problem and, without it, it's impossible to tell you something meaningful.